# Is there way to have JSON with custom set of data and use it server side with Shopify?

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I got liquid script that depending on "**product id**" displays some custom images,  text and other data, the way to solve it i've came with was to create snipplet of following code (code is generated offline with tool i created and just put into theme later).

**productGroup-data.liquid**

```
{% if productGroup-data == '43542321' %}
    {% capture prod_group_info %}3|foo0|foo1|foo2{% endcapture %}
{% elsif productGroup-data == '43542322' %}
    {% capture prod_group_info %}0|{% endcapture %}
{% elsif productGroup-data == '43542323' %}
    {% capture prod_group_info %}1|foo1{% endcapture %}
{% elsif productGroup-data == '43542324' %}
    {% capture prod_group_info %}2|foo1|foo2{% endcapture %}
...
{% endif %}
```

And then i call this snipplet if needed and make use of **productGroup-data** but i guess that this solution is not best and in fact it might cause problems if that tree of **if statement** grows over 64kb.

I use such **if statement** tree in few places, example above is just simplest of cases, so that much more is crucial for me to find a solution.

Is there a way to access JSON file from assets or different place in theme folders derver side? To store and access custom data in more elegant way? As it  happens with **settings** and **theme language** already?

All that **if statement** code makes files to expand very quickly and I'am afraid i will run out allowed file size soon.

If not JSON then what other options in bounds of store do i got to store such data? Creating  custom online app for shopify is kond over my skill so this is not an option for me.

Comment: Why can't you use product metafields?

Comment: @HymnZ it is not only about products i do also cover other aspects of shop like pages for example, and still JSON file is more easy to introduce and then manage than metafields, as i told before script generated by offline app is just put into theme and it should work. So tell me metafields are my only option or is there more?

Comment: @HymnZ and do you know what is max lenght of metafield value, and if page or product got one or more metafields? Shopify API docs lets me understand that it got only one metafield so I'm confused

Comment: You can use metafields for all things mentioned in the API docs. Also there is no limit on the number of metafields or the length of metafield. I use pretty long metafield values.